# Correct way to declare property whose type is an enum value

Tags: objective-c

I want my class to have a property that can only be assigned a value from an enum, but I can't quite get the syntax straight in my mind. This is my header file:

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SPSSearchResultsOrder) {
  SPSSearchResultsOrderAlphabetical,
  SPSSearchResultsOrderPrice
};

@interface SPSSearchQuery : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic) enum SPSSearchResultsorder searchResultsOrder;

// etc.

@end
```

Xcode suggested I add the `enum` keyword to my property declaration to get the code to compile, which is why I don't think this is right.

Should the property be typed as `NSInteger` as that's the type of the enum? In which case, how do I enforce that the property can only be assigned one of the enum's values?

If I was writing this in Java I'd do something like this:

```
public enum SearchResultsOrder {
  SearchResultsOrderAlphabetical,
  SearchResultsOrderPrice;
}

public class SearchQuery
  private SearchResultsOrder searchResultsOrder;

  public SearchResultsOrder getSearchResultsOrder() {
    return this.searchResultsOrder;
  }
}
```

—As you can see, here the compiler is able to enforce the relationship between the enum and the member variable's type. What's the Objective-C equivalent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if You add `typedef` in front on `NS_ENUM`, then you can refer to your enum type as `SPSSearchResults` without `enum` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were moving in the right direction. You should `typedef` enums in order to use them as a type:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SPSSearchResultsOrder) {
    SPSSearchResultsOrderAlphabetical,
    SPSSearchResultsOrderPrice
};

@interface SPSSearchQuery : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) SPSSearchResultsorder searchResultsOrder;

@end
```

Also as your property holds not an object but a type value (`NSInteger` in your case) you should use the `assign` keyword. This keyword opts out of ARC memory management setters/getters that are generated for this property.

The `NS_ENUM` macro is actually a *preferable* way to declare enums in Cocoa. With that approach you'll receive *typechecking* and *code completion* in Xcode. If you take a look into Apple's frameworks you'll see that it is used everywhere instead of plain enums. Respect the coding style of the platform! :)

Comment: Yes; the `assign` attribute is the key here!

Comment: This works, but interestingly it still doesn't constrain the value of `searchResultsOrder` to one of the constants in the enum. For example, I can assign 3 to the instance variable backing the property. I can live with that though because the assignment only happens within my class's initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be `NSInteger` if you've used `NS_ENUM` to define the enum.

However I never use `NS_ENUM` and prefer the normal C syntax, which is simpler and means the proper type can be used:

```
enum SPSSearchResultsOrder {
  SPSSearchResultsOrderAlphabetical,
  SPSSearchResultsOrderPrice
};

...

@property (readonly, nonatomic) SPSSearchResultsOrder searchResultsOrder;
```

(note you have `SPSSearchResultsorder` in your code).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I used `NS_ENUM` because that seems to be the preferred way to do things nowadays: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Comment: @JohnTopley Yeah maybe.  I never hit the problems it was designed to fix I guess...

Comment: Using NS_ENUM/OPTIONS allows the Swift compiler to convert your enums to Swift enums properly.

Comment: @Lance Another reason **not** to use it then ;-)

Comment: @Lance That's interesting to know, but this code won't be upgraded to Swift.

Comment: @JohnTopley even if it won't, it'll make it so anyone who wants to use that code in swift later won't have problems :)